# Favoriting a song in iTunes scrolls to top and collapses album view

Tags: macos, click, album, itunes

So.. this issue has been killing me for a while. I imagine others are having this too, so I am going to post quite a bit of info here.

The issue is pretty basic. When I have an album open in iTunes I can double click a song to play it. All goes well, but when I click the heart next to the song (to remove or add a favorite) the album view will collapse and then I will be scrolled to the top of the albums view window.

This issue persists between operating systems, too. For example if I favorite a song in iTunes on a Windows machine, the same behavior occurs (although the album view isn't collapsed in Windows for some reason).

Here is the bug in action documented via GIF image:

[image: The Bug in Action (gif)]

I have a feeling this is specific to my user account, so here is some history that may be helpful.

I subscribed to iTunes match before Apple Music was here. I cancelled my iTunes match account before Apple Music came out.

I am now an Apple Music subscriber and I have a mix of Apple Music and purchased content. Favoriting a song from either source causes the issue.

Comment: Probably a bug. Submit a bug report to Apple: https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: @user14492 I was afraid of that, but I figured putting this out on the web would be good for others experiencing the problem. I'll report back here when I find out more. To anyone else finding this, you are not alone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I might know the answer to this one: Go to the 'Albums' dropdown in the toolbar (nearly top-right) and turn off 'Show Recently Added'.

What might be happening is that a two-year old bug around one of the elements in the Recently Added section is getting focus, which scrolls the entire view to the top. It drove me completely crazy until I finally found this

Comment: Sure enough, this seemed to be a valid work around! No more scrolling to the top or collapsing of views.